# Getting Ubuntu 14.10 Unity Launcher to launch Android-Studio

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, launcher, ubuntu-unity

I am having trouble getting Ubuntu Unity Launcher to launch Android-Studio. Here is my desktop file:

```
more Android-studio.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Android-studio
Comment=Android Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/home/jumbo/android-studio/bin/idea
Exec=/home/jumbo/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Android;
StartupWMClass=Android-studio
Name[en_GB]=Android-studio
```

I copied the above from the Ubuntu web site but the icon blinks several times and then nothing happens.

I can find no clear instructions through Google browser.

Does unity launcher store launch errors?

Comment: how did you installed Android-Studio?

Comment: Android-Studio works ok if I cd to the bin directory: "cd /home/jumbo/android-studio/bin", then ./studio.sh

Comment: try adding to your code: ' StartupNotify=true', alternatively, Android Studio->Tools->Create Desktop Entry.

Comment: I added ' StartupNotify=true' as you suggested, and it now works! Magic. Thank you.  How did you find this out?

Comment: you are welcome, glad to help, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding to your code: `StartupNotify=true`

"This command in the desktop file enables the desktop to use whatever startup notification is built in to either your application or your toolkit."

for more details: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/startup-notification.html.en

Answer (score 1):

You will love this: (1) Go into your-> .Android Studio directory/folder in your GUI your ./studio.sh file should be there. 
    ->(2)Right click inside the folder
    ->(3) Open Terminal here
    ->(4)Type: ./studio.sh ->Android Studio will open up the flash screen-> When Android Studio fully opens
    ->(5)Look on menu bar 
    -> (6)Find:Tools 
    -> (7)Choose: Create Desktop Entry 
    ->(8)After it self configures (as your machine audibly roils with the new configuration):PRESTO!!!

Comment: I tried this twice, (before putting my question here) and it put an icon on the launcher. But it didn't work, both times I tried!

Comment: Just tried your EXACT instructions, and YES it WORKED! Brill!

Comment: I just followed the directions and when I executed the script, I saw this: > ~$ AndroidStudio  
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/usr/local/bin/AndroidStudio", line 99, in <module>  
> os.execv(bin_file, [bin_file] + args)  
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry
```

[image]

It will work